# Why I can't find vendor/autoload.php for Google Calendar API?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am following all steps to run a PHP Google Calendar Api. I followed this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php . In step 4 it asks to run quickstart.php, but as after running the file, it displayed me this error :

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Calendar\google-api-php-client-master\quickstart.php
>   on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Calendar\google-api-php-client-master\quickstart.php
>   on line 2

Comment: welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Here's a check-list for you to go down with Composer and vendor/autoload.php:

- Does your `composer.json` file exist in the root of your project? (Note: This may be up a level from your document root for your web server.)
- Does the `vendor` folder exist in the same folder as your `composer.json`?
- Are you using the correct relative path to find your `vendor/autoload.php` file?

If `composer.json` isn't in your project root, move it there. It's where it belongs and things will continue to go wrong for you until it's there.

The `vendor` folder and its `autoload.php` file are both automatically created when you run `php composer.phar install` or `php composer.phar update`. If they're missing, you need to run `php composer.phar install`.

Once you've verified that `vendor/autoload.php` exists and is in the correct location, make sure that you have a good relative reference to that file with your `require` statement.

Comment: Hello @Michael , I am a beginner , I installed composer while standing at Home directory so it created the vendor folder in the home directory , so in my php that uses `require vendor/autoload.php` should  contain this vendor folder alongside or it can pick up automatically ?

Comment: All of these commands, files, and folders should exist in your project root folder, not your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue using the followed command:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

I would execute it inside of the application folder.

**Example:**

```
c:\<< your_app_folder >>\composer dump-autoload -o.
```

After that, you will see the "vendor" folder. The autoload.php file will inside.

> For more information, access the link:
>   http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me
make sure you have composer installed then try the below command in your terminal

```bash
  composer update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).